# powershell Collection was modified stop all running manual services

Tags: powershell

The following powershell statement fails with the message: *Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.*

```
Get-Service | Select-Object -Property Name,Status,StartType | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running" -and $_.StartType -eq "Manual"} | Stop-Service -Force
```

The solution is to not enumerate and stop but to first convert the items to an array/list but I can't find how to do that.

I would expect something like `ToArray` or `ToList` as is possible in c# and then iterate over the array instead of using the services enumerator but I cannot find powershell documentation on  how to do this.

I only see samples that do something with a `foreach` that are converted to a `for` but I would like to keep it a oneline and just want to convert the enumerable to an list/array.\

Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign to a variable before calling `Stop-Service`:

```
$servicesToStop = Get-Service |Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running" -and $_.StartType -eq "Manual"}
$servicesToStop |Stop-Service -Force
```